# Placing random objects on screen in blank area in Corona

Tags: android, iphone, lua, coronasdk

I want to place objects on the free area randomly on the screen for that i am using contentBounds to find the free area on the screen and then place below is the code i am using but it is not working properly. They both are overlapping sometimes.Please help to solve it.

```
local getbounds=obj1.contentBounds
local boundXmin=getbounds.xMin
local boundXmax=getbounds.xMax
local boundYmin=getbounds.yMin
local boundYmax=getbounds.ymax
local xPos=generate_random_no(20,800)
local yPos=generate_random_no(30,400)
if(xPos>=boundXmin and xPos<=boundXmax) or (yPos>=boundYmin and yPos<=boundYmin) then
  local shiftobj=boundXMax-XPos
  Obj.x=xPos+shiftobj
else
  Obj.x=xPos
end
```

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate if your other question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357537/display-random-objects-in-corona-without-overlapping-on-the-other-objects-on-scr?

Answer (score 0):

You are generating bad random positions. Try:

```
xPos = generate_random_no(xMin, xMax)
yPos = generate_random_no(yMin, yMax)
```

This will give you random coordinates inside your boundaries and you wont have to